# Lost connection to mysql server during query while creating index but still getting the index afterwards

Tags: mysql, indexing, mysql-workbench

I hava a table containing 38 millions of rows of entry. To make eventual queries faster, I thought to create index on some columns.

While creating index on one column, it runs for approximate 2 hours then shows:

```
Lost connection to MySQL server during query
```

However if I restart the mySql workbench, which I'm working on, it shows my new index there. I have two questions:

1) Is the new index that got created is a complete one or an incomplete/invalid one?

2) How to resolve the lost connection problem? 
From Edit>Preferences>SQL Editor: I have changed the values for DBMS connection read time-out and 2 others to a large value. But that doesn't help.

Comment: I don't think MySQL will have rolled back index creation just because your client went away. As for how to stop tcp connections breaking..

Comment: I am not sure I understand your comment. Can you explain? @CaiusJard

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Index creation is an atomic operation, in the sense that it will either succeed entirely or fail entirely... so if you have an index, it will be intact and complete.

The reason you are losing your connection is most likely the network --at least one device (such as a firewall, or a NAT router, or if this a cloud-based server, it may be a device in the cloud provider's infrastructure) in the network path between you and the server maintains a TCP flow state table of active TCP sessions, and with no data transferred for some period of time, the connection is purged from that device's memory, so the connection collapses.

The MySQL client/server protocol has no layer 7 keep-alive mechanism for keeping idle connections open on the network... and from the network's perspective, the connection is completely idle during an index creation operation.

It may be possible to change kernel-level parameters on client and/or server so that some keep-alive messages are exchanged closer to layer 4, keeping the connection alive at a lower level, but this is system specific ([Linux example](http://tldp.org/HOWTO/TCP-Keepalive-HOWTO/usingkeepalive.html)).

Often it is also possible to speed up index creation greatly on MySQL by disabling foreign key checks on your connection only, while adding the index.  Don't do this unless you are absolutely sure that your index operation doesn't jeopardize any data integrity (i.e., don't use this unless you are not adding a *foreign* key).

```
mysql> SET @@FOREIGN_KEY_CHECKS = 0;
mysql> ALTER TABLE ADD KEY ...;
mysql> SET @@FOREIGN_KEY_CHECKS = 1;
```

Note also that if you are using the GUI from Workbench to add indexes rather than actually typing SQL statements to alter the table... don't do that.  Using graphical tools for DDL increases the odds of your time being wasted because they sometimes generate statements that accomplish the purpose you intended, but do it in a very inefficient and sometimes illogical way.

In many cases you can also use this:

```
mysql> ALTER TABLE ALGORITHM=INPLACE, LOCK=NONE, ADD KEY ...;
```

These options speed up the index operation by avoiding unnecessary locking and by attaching the index to the table as it stands, rather than copying the table.  If the server doesn't like these options for the particular operation you're performing, it will tell you so, with an error, and no harm will be done.   The `ALGORITHM` and `LOCK` options sometimes need to be preceded by disabling the foreign key checks, and enabling them when you are done.

Worth repeating: turning off foreign key checks as shown above only impacts one single connection -- yours -- and not any other connection.  This doesn't disable checks for the table being altered if it is accessed by other users, or even by you, if you access the same table from another connection.  This setting doesn't jeopardize data integrity as long as you don't do anything that disturbs foreign key references while you have it disabled.  It's a well-known and commonly-used optimization.  The checks are not needed when you're adding indexes but the server will in some cases try to validate the existing data unnecessarily.